# NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 80: Unable to init from given url (https://example.net/img/picture.png?1549836294)

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

How to fix this laravel error?

> NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 80: Unable to init
>   from given url (https://example.net/img/picture.png?1549836294)

*Here is my code:*
**AbstractDecoder.php**

```
    public function initFromUrl($url)
{

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n".
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2\r\n"
      )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);


    if ($data = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context)) {
        return $this->initFromBinary($data);
    }

    throw new \Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException(
        "Unable to init from given url (".$url.")."
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you expected to happen so other users of the site can help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`https://example.net/img/picture.png?1549836294` is not an image.

You need to replace the url in the example code you copied with a url that *does* return an image.